# Is Graph Theory is compulsory/essential for learning Combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

Is Graph Theory is  compulsory/essential  for learning Combinatorics ?

Im newly learning combinatorics ,

I have two doubts in my mind

$1.$ why graph theory is included in most of the combinatorics books ?

$2.$ Can i learn combinatorics  without graph theory ?

Comment: Graph theory is widely considered a branch of combinatorics, though it is also sometimes considered a separate field in its own right. You can learn other parts of combinatorics without learning much graph theory, but I would strongly advise learning at least the basics.

Comment: okss , thanks u sir @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You’re welcome.